# change boolvalue in ViewContro. B when you press button in ViewControl A, iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring

i have a NSString property in viewcontroller MainProfileViewController called "TriggerReload"

When i press a button in Viewcontroller A, i want that the string "TriggerReload" change to @"yes".. without going to the MainProfileViewController!!

This is the code when i press the button in VC A:

```
MainProfileViewController *mainProf = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainProfileViewController"];
            mainProf.TriggerReload = @"yes";
            NSLog(@"%@",mainProf.TriggerReload);
```

The NSLOG SAYS "YES"

But when i go to the mainprofileviewcontroller manually (because i want it to go manually) and put in the viewdidload

```
NSLog (@"%@",TriggerReload)
```

The NSLOG Says 'null'

Could anyone help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you already have a `MainProfileViewController` that you've created previously (in a storyboard or something) and that you also don't present `mainProf` after setting `mainProf.TriggerReload`.

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` creates a new controller object.  It does not give you a reference to one you already have.  You can't change a property in one instance and expect it to change the matching property in a different instance.

Look at using a delegate or notification to tell your original `MainProfileViewController` that it should change.